# Algorithm used in Achartengine

Tags: achartengine

I'd like to ask what algorithms have been used in the achartengine? Is Dijkstra's algorithm used in here or any other algorithms? I'm learning algorithms as of now. And if you could give me recommendations where to start, I'd gladly appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No fancy algorithm has been used in AChartEngine. The only one is for transforming real data to screen coordinates.